# Как осуществить 100 запросов к Google без капчи?

Tags: captcha, поисковые-системы

Как осуществить 100 запросов к Google без капчи, используя прокси? Как это возможно автоматизировать ?

Comment: Стоит начать с 1 запроса

Answer (score 1):

Selenium, tor (указать регион относящийся к запросам и смена ip раз в 20 сёк) и профиль в котором пару дней работал живой человек

Comment: Вот как раз об тор и будут проблемы. Точек выхода немного, и они все время от времени попадают в "софт-бан" гуглов, яндексов и прочих клаудфаров. У меня с моей живой гуглоучёткой все вводы капчи - только когда тором пользуюсь.

Comment: Использовал для яндекса количество запросов кап и с тором гораздо меньше чем без